# Valid placeholder solution for IE with jQuery on XHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, xhtml

Are there any **valid** solutions for input placeholders for XHTML that also work in Internet Explorer 7+ besides Chrome and Firefox?

In **HTML5** I had:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search..." maxlength="30" />
```

Since I'm using XHTML now, it comes up as invalid XHTML because the placeholder attribute is not supported. Also it's not supported in Internet Explorer 9-.

Comment: [InFieldLabels](https://github.com/dcneiner/In-Field-Labels-jQuery-Plugin) might suit your needs. Even though it is technically invalid as XHTML, jQuery won't care because it will still find the `placeholder` attribute.

Comment: I see your edit. It works without the `placeholder` as well [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5xDqD/)

Comment: I tested the [samples](http://fuelyourcoding.com/scripts/infield/)  with IETester, and it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: The website features v0.1 (out-of-date) and GitHub has v0.1.3 so you will have to test with the latest version

Comment: @KidDiamond any reason you can't use XHTML5? It's just the XML valid version of HTML5

Comment: Is it supported by IE7+?

Comment: IETester's reliability is questionable at best. If you are placing such an emphasis on making it work in that browser then either native or VM is the way to go.

Comment: With regards to polyfills and now-standard attribute names, I won't worry too much about whether or not your markup is going to be considered *valid*, at least not when we're talking about the polyfilled portions. There are numerous placeholder polyfills out there; pick one, put it into play, and continue to write otherwise valid markup. This is totally acceptable.